# Изменение параметров MySQL без прав суперпользователя

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Мне нужно поменять параметр `wait_timeout` в моей MySQL базе данных. Однако если я выполняю команду

```
set global wait_timeout = 28800
[2020-12-29 20:08:32] [42000][1227] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
[2020-12-29 20:08:32] [42000][1227] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Мне выдаёт ошибку, что требуются права суперпользователя.
Возможно ли как то поменять параметры MySQL только для моего пользователя, что бы они применялись только к моим подключениям, так как я не могу получить права админа.

Answer (score 0):

Параметр [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) может быть как глобальным, так и сессионным. Для изменения параметров сессии никаких особых прав не нужно. Делается это одним запросом (любым из - выбирайте по вкусу)

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout := {новое значение};
SET LOCAL wait_timeout := {новое значение};
SET @@SESSION.wait_timeout := {новое значение};
SET @@LOCAL.wait_timeout := {новое значение};
SET @@wait_timeout := {новое значение};
SET wait_timeout := {новое значение};
```

Но куда как разумнее добавить установку этого параметра в дополнительные команды соединения - тогда параметр будет устанавливаться автоматически в момент подключения, и никаких дополнительных телодвижений делать не требуется.